# Reading an image resource file in java

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I've been searching to find out how to solve this problem for some time now, but I can't seem to find a way. I could read the image as long as it was in eclipse, but when I exported it, it was impossible. I tried with an InputStream, but that throws an IllegalArgumentException for some reason, what am I doing wrong?

```
InputStream iconstream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/icon.png");

InputStream pigstream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/pig.png");
```

This is for getting the resources, and here is where I read them:

```
try {
            icon = ImageIO.read(iconstream);
            pig = ImageIO.read(pigstream);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

[image: My file Tree]

Comment: Share your file tree please

Comment: Check if your image is being exported to .jar file. (If, of course, you use it in your program as an icon of some sort). If it does, check the path inside jar file.

Comment: @Sibidharan My file tree is here now

Comment: You are running a jar after compiling? So place your resources folder in the same dir where your jar is! Be sure to use the same working code which you was using in eclipse. Problem solved. @ItzBenteThePig

Comment: @Sibidharan Didn't work, sorry.

Comment: Please share the file tree of your jar and resources folder @ItzBenteThePig

Comment: @Sibidharan How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Ok now first say how you are exporting your project or build and in which format? @ItzBenteThePig

Comment: @Sibidharan I'm just right clicking the project, and exporting it as a runnable jar file.

Comment: Now locate the jar file in explorer and can you see the resources folder near to it? @ItzBenteThePig

Comment: Mark `resources` folder as resources (if you didn't already, I don't remember how that looks in eclipse). Then in your code remove `resource/` from paths (leave just `"icon.png"` and `"pig.png"`) and everything should work.  If it doesn't try marking `resource` folder as source and rebuild again. The point is, eclipse should know that it has to export those images to .jar file

Comment: Do resources/*.png files exist in jar file? Rename to .zip and open it if doubt.

Comment: @Meegoo It worked, thanks

Comment: @Whome I have winrar, so I could just open it directly, I fixed it now though, so don't worry

Answer (score 1):

change

```
InputStream iconstream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/icon.png");
```

to

```
InputStream iconstream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/icon.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

`getClass().getResourceAsStream()` looks in the package of the class. You either need to add a leading `/` to the name or else use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`.