# I can access a file in ide, but it doesn't work on cmd

Tags: java, swing

Hi I want to add images on Jpanel. when I clicked the run button on IDE, It works. But when I export the project as a jar file it doesn't work. it says that file doesn't exist. I don't know what causes the problem.
sorry for my bad English.

```
package avoidingGame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class DroppingObject extends JPanel
{
  public DroppingObject() {
      try {
          File poop = new File("./img/pngtree-a-cute-brawn-turd-vector-or-color-illustration-png-image_2030317-removebg-preview.png");
          System.out.println("isFile is= "+ poop.isFile());
          System.out.println("fileExists is= "+ poop.exists());
          BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(poop);
          Image image = bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(70, 70, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
          JLabel pic = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
          pic.setOpaque(false);
          add(pic);
          setBounds(130, 180, 70, 70); // 크기설정
      }
      
      catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("failed to load image");
      }
  }  
}
```

```
     the result is that
    isFile is = true 
    fileExists is true 
     on IDE.
```

but both are false in cmd

Comment: You're using a relative file path.  Your cmd would only work if you execute the command in the same directory as your .class file.  [Reading an image resource file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251648/reading-an-image-resource-file-in-java)

Comment: Better to load your files/images as resources:
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
[Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)

Comment: And btw your problem is a [current directory](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java)
issue

Comment: there is no __file__ path in a jar, it's a __package__ in a resource lookup

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong.
If you run the .jar file, your computer will search in that directory:

```
./img/pngtree-a-cute-brawn-turd-vector-or-color-illustration-png-image_2030317-removebg-preview.png
```

your machine will not find anything, because you did not provide the absolute path.

You need to input the absolute path. for example:

```
/Users/yourUser/Pictures/yourPic.jpg
```

**if you just put in the \img path, your IDE will recognize it, because it has the mother directory already open. So it will just search in that. If you run as jar, on the other hand, your machine will not know where EXACTLY the File is located.That's because the .jar file and the cmd window is not located in your project folder.**